# Spining up couchdb in hyperledger fabric

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, leveldb, hyperledger-chaincode

How to spring up couchdb in Hyperledger fabric in development mode for chaincode because by default its takes leveldb as a state database. So in order to perform rich queries couchdb has to be used as state database (I am following Hyperledger fabric official documentation).

Comment: Do you mean "spin" instead of "sping"?

Comment: which fabric version are you using, and what do you mean exactly by "development mode"?

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB isn't embedded in Fabric like LevelDB is. You have to run the instance yourself and then configure Fabric to use it. See the official documentarion here for configuring it:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/couchdb_tutorial.html